# Crystal report to SSRS : Evaluating running total only on change of Field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a Crystal report that uses RunningTotal field with following criteria:

Field to summarize: `Balance`

Type Of summary: `sum`

Evaluate: on change of Field `VictimProgramPK`

Now, I have a requirement to convert this report to SSRS. How can i convert above RunningTotalField to SSRS expression using `RunningValue()` ?

Comment: Yes, and group on the VictimProgramPK. Or you could have subtotals based on that PK. It depends on how you want it to look in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the group:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Balance.Value,SUM,"GroupVictimProgramPK")
```

https://gerryhubi.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/ssrs-tips-runningvalue/

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution only works for Count, not for other summary types. There are two solutions for this, one is to use SSRS LookupSet function, it will always work. Another is do some work in the database level, for example write a stored procedure to do the calculation.